# php extension gd not working php7.4.21 (Parrot Os)

Tags: php, debian, php-7.4, php-gd, parrot-os

I have search all over the internet just to find a solution for this problem.
I have php7.4 installed on my system. I have been struggling with the php-gd extension. I have been able to install the extension and yet when i try to run any php application that is using the extension, i get the error that, the extension is not installed.
I removed it, install it and is still the same.
i remove php7.4 itself and reinstall it but is still the same.
After installing php8.0 and the extension with the same method, it works fine.
please help.
This is what i get in the terminal everytime i try to use a php app that requires php-gd.

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is locked to version 1.14.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.1 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Can you show your code ? You error ? If it works with php8, it's fine ? Maybe you install the php-gd for php8 instead of php7.4

Comment: That's the problem. it wasn't working for php7.4 so install php8 and it was working fine. But i need to use php7.4 not 8.0. The problem is that, my system is saying it has been installed even though, when am using any php app that requires php-gd it says it is not installed

Comment: And if you reinstall php7. 4 with all dependencies, it doesn't works? Also, are you sure it's designed for php7 ? Finally, maybe you can install it manually by editing php config

Comment: yes i tried to reinstall php7.4 and install the gd extension. The problem is not with the installation. i have been able to install it but when am to use any app that require the extension, it tells me the extension is not installed. Please how do i edit the php config file. am using parrot os